# Heroku help rails app crashing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku

My app is crashing on heroku and I dont know what the reason is.

Update new heroku log:

```
PC@I-PC /c/rails/myapp (master)
$ heroku logs
2011-05-04T17:56:06+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/r
ack-1.2.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:46:in `instance_eval'
2011-05-04T17:56:06+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/r
ack-1.2.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:46:in `initialize'
2011-05-04T17:56:06+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /home/heroku_rack/heroku.ru:1:in `n
ew'
2011-05-04T17:56:06+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /home/heroku_rack/heroku.ru:1:in `<
main>'
2011-05-04T17:56:06+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /usr/ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/
gems/thin-1.2.6/lib/rack/adapter/loader.rb:36:in `eval'
2011-05-04T17:56:06+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /usr/ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/
gems/thin-1.2.6/lib/rack/adapter/loader.rb:36:in `load'
2011-05-04T17:56:06+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /usr/ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/
gems/thin-1.2.6/lib/thin/controllers/controller.rb:175:in `load_rackup_config'
2011-05-04T17:56:06+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /usr/ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/
gems/thin-1.2.6/lib/thin/controllers/controller.rb:65:in `start'
2011-05-04T17:56:06+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /usr/ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/
gems/thin-1.2.6/lib/thin/runner.rb:177:in `run_command'
2011-05-04T17:56:06+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /usr/ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/
gems/thin-1.2.6/lib/thin/runner.rb:143:in `run!'
2011-05-04T10:56:07-07:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2011-05-04T11:05:57-07:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to created
2011-05-04T11:05:57-07:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from created to starting
2011-05-04T18:06:08+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesu
pport-3.0.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:304:in `rescue in depend_on': No
such file to load -- scraper (LoadError)
2011-05-04T18:06:08+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/a
ctivesupport-3.0.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:299:in `depend_on'
2011-05-04T18:06:08+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/a
ctivesupport-3.0.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:216:in `require_dependency
'
2011-05-04T18:06:08+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/r
ailties-3.0.3/lib/rails/engine.rb:138:in `block (2 levels) in eager_load!'
2011-05-04T18:06:08+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/r
ailties-3.0.3/lib/rails/engine.rb:137:in `each'
2011-05-04T18:06:08+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/r
ailties-3.0.3/lib/rails/engine.rb:137:in `block in eager_load!'
2011-05-04T18:06:08+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/r
ailties-3.0.3/lib/rails/engine.rb:135:in `each'
2011-05-04T18:06:08+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/r
ailties-3.0.3/lib/rails/engine.rb:135:in `eager_load!'
2011-05-04T18:06:08+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/r
ailties-3.0.3/lib/rails/application/railties.rb:11:in `each'
2011-05-04T18:06:08+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/r
ailties-3.0.3/lib/rails/application/railties.rb:11:in `all'
2011-05-04T18:06:08+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/r
ailties-3.0.3/lib/rails/application.rb:107:in `eager_load!'
2011-05-04T18:06:08+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/r
ailties-3.0.3/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:41:in `block in <module:Finisher
>'
2011-05-04T18:06:08+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/r
ailties-3.0.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:25:in `instance_exec'
2011-05-04T18:06:08+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/r
ailties-3.0.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:25:in `run'
2011-05-04T18:06:08+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/r
ailties-3.0.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:50:in `block in run_initializers'
2011-05-04T18:06:08+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/r
ailties-3.0.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:49:in `each'
2011-05-04T18:06:08+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/r
ailties-3.0.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:49:in `run_initializers'
2011-05-04T18:06:08+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/r
ailties-3.0.3/lib/rails/application.rb:134:in `initialize!'
2011-05-04T18:06:08+00:00 app[web.1]:   from <internal:lib/rubygems/custom_requi
re>:29:in `require'
2011-05-04T18:06:08+00:00 app[web.1]:   from config.ru:3:in `block (3 levels) in
 <main>'
2011-05-04T18:06:08+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/r
ack-1.2.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:46:in `instance_eval'
2011-05-04T18:06:08+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/r
ack-1.2.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:46:in `initialize'
2011-05-04T18:06:08+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /home/heroku_rack/heroku.ru:11:in `
new'
2011-05-04T18:06:08+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /home/heroku_rack/heroku.ru:11:in `
block in <main>'
2011-05-04T18:06:08+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /home/heroku_rack/heroku.ru:1:in `n
ew'
2011-05-04T18:06:08+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /usr/ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/
gems/thin-1.2.6/lib/thin/controllers/controller.rb:175:in `load_rackup_config'
2011-05-04T18:06:08+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /usr/ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/
gems/thin-1.2.6/lib/thin/controllers/controller.rb:65:in `start'
2011-05-04T18:06:08+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /usr/ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/
gems/thin-1.2.6/lib/thin/runner.rb:177:in `run_command'
2011-05-04T18:06:08+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /usr/ruby1.9.2/bin/thin:19:in `<mai
n>'
2011-05-04T11:06:09-07:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2011-05-04T11:15:12-07:00 heroku[slugc]: Slug compilation started
2011-05-04T11:16:23-07:00 heroku[api]: Deploy c515040 by mail@mydomain.dk

2011-05-04T11:16:23-07:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to created
2011-05-04T11:16:23-07:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from created to starting
2011-05-04T11:16:24-07:00 heroku[slugc]: Slug compilation finished
2011-05-04T11:16:25-07:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to created
2011-05-04T11:16:25-07:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from created to starting
2011-05-04T18:16:33+00:00 app[web.1]: >> Thin web server (v1.2.6 codename Crazy
Delicious)
2011-05-04T18:16:33+00:00 app[web.1]: >> Maximum connections set to 1024
2011-05-04T18:16:33+00:00 app[web.1]: >> Listening on 0.0.0.0:16016, CTRL+C to s
top
2011-05-04T11:16:34-07:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2011-05-04T11:16:55-07:00 heroku[slugc]: Slug compilation started
2011-05-04T11:18:03-07:00 heroku[api]: Deploy fe898f9 by mail@mydomain.dk

2011-05-04T11:18:03-07:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to bouncing
2011-05-04T11:18:03-07:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from created to starting
2011-05-04T11:18:03-07:00 heroku[slugc]: Slug compilation finished
2011-05-04T18:18:05+00:00 app[web.1]: >> Stopping ...
2011-05-04T18:18:12+00:00 app[web.1]: >> Thin web server (v1.2.6 codename Crazy
Delicious)
2011-05-04T18:18:12+00:00 app[web.1]: >> Maximum connections set to 1024
2011-05-04T18:18:12+00:00 app[web.1]: >> Listening on 0.0.0.0:27899, CTRL+C to s
top
2011-05-04T11:18:12-07:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2011-05-04T18:18:12+00:00 app[web.1]:
2011-05-04T18:18:12+00:00 app[web.1]:
2011-05-04T18:18:12+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/" for myip at 2011
-05-04 20:18:12 +0200
2011-05-04T18:18:13+00:00 heroku[router]: GET vinderhimlen.dk/ dyno=web.1 queue=
0 wait=0ms service=57ms bytes=386
2011-05-04T18:18:13+00:00 app[web.1]:
2011-05-04T18:18:13+00:00 app[web.1]:
2011-05-04T18:18:13+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/" for myip at 2011
-05-04 20:18:13 +0200
2011-05-04T11:18:13-07:00 heroku[nginx]: GET / HTTP/1.1 | myip | 436 |
 http | 301
2011-05-04T18:18:13+00:00 app[web.1]:
2011-05-04T18:18:13+00:00 app[web.1]: ActionView::MissingTemplate (Missing layou
t layouts/Application with {:handlers=>[:erb, :rjs, :builder, :rhtml, :rxml], :f
ormats=>[:html], :locale=>[:en, :en]} in view paths "/app/app/views", "/app/vend
or/plugins/tinymce_hammer/app/views", "/app/vendor/plugins/rails_log_stdout/app/
views", "/app/vendor/plugins/rails3_disable_x_sendfile/app/views", "/app/.bundle
/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/devise-1.3.4/app/views", "/app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gem
s/kaminari-0.12.4/app/views"):
2011-05-04T18:18:13+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/controllers/public_controller.rb:13:
in `index'
2011-05-04T18:18:13+00:00 app[web.1]:
2011-05-04T18:18:13+00:00 app[web.1]:
2011-05-04T18:18:13+00:00 heroku[router]: GET www.mydomain.dk/ dyno=web.1 qu
eue=0 wait=0ms service=272ms bytes=934
2011-05-04T11:18:14-07:00 heroku[nginx]: GET / HTTP/1.1 | myip | 965 |
 http | 500
2011-05-04T18:18:17+00:00 heroku[router]: GET www.mydomain.dk/favicon.ico dy
no=web.1 queue=0 wait=0ms service=1ms bytes=225
2011-05-04T11:20:26-07:00 heroku[slugc]: Slug compilation started
2011-05-04T11:21:40-07:00 heroku[api]: Deploy 0a6f7f5 by mail@mydomain.dk

2011-05-04T11:21:41-07:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to bouncing
2011-05-04T11:21:41-07:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from created to starting
2011-05-04T11:21:41-07:00 heroku[slugc]: Slug compilation finished
2011-05-04T18:21:42+00:00 app[web.1]: >> Stopping ...
2011-05-04T18:21:55+00:00 app[web.1]: >> Thin web server (v1.2.6 codename Crazy
Delicious)
2011-05-04T18:21:55+00:00 app[web.1]: >> Maximum connections set to 1024
2011-05-04T18:21:55+00:00 app[web.1]: >> Listening on 0.0.0.0:46369, CTRL+C to s
top
2011-05-04T11:21:56-07:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2011-05-04T18:22:00+00:00 app[web.1]:
2011-05-04T18:22:00+00:00 app[web.1]:
2011-05-04T18:22:00+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/" for myip at 2011
-05-04 20:22:00 +0200
2011-05-04T18:22:01+00:00 heroku[router]: GET www.mydomain.dk/ dyno=web.1 qu
eue=0 wait=0ms service=536ms bytes=934
2011-05-04T18:22:01+00:00 app[web.1]:
2011-05-04T18:22:01+00:00 app[web.1]: ActionView::MissingTemplate (Missing layou
t layouts/Application with {:handlers=>[:erb, :rjs, :builder, :rhtml, :rxml], :f
ormats=>[:html], :locale=>[:en, :en]} in view paths "/app/app/views", "/app/vend
or/plugins/tinymce_hammer/app/views", "/app/vendor/plugins/rails_log_stdout/app/
views", "/app/vendor/plugins/rails3_disable_x_sendfile/app/views", "/app/.bundle
/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/devise-1.3.4/app/views", "/app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gem
s/kaminari-0.12.4/app/views"):
2011-05-04T18:22:01+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/controllers/public_controller.rb:13:
in `index'
2011-05-04T18:22:01+00:00 app[web.1]:
2011-05-04T18:22:01+00:00 app[web.1]:
2011-05-04T11:22:01-07:00 heroku[nginx]: GET / HTTP/1.1 | myip | 964 |
 http | 500

PC@I-PC /c/rails/myapp (master)
```

Old heroku log:

```
PC /c/rails/myapp (master)
$ heroku logs
2011-05-04T13:09:18+00:00 app[web.1]:   from config.ru:3:in `block (3 levels) in
 <main>'
2011-05-04T13:09:18+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /home/heroku_rack/heroku.ru:23:in `
eval'
2011-05-04T13:09:18+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /home/heroku_rack/heroku.ru:23:in `
block (3 levels) in <main>'
2011-05-04T13:09:18+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/r
ack-1.2.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:46:in `instance_eval'
2011-05-04T13:09:18+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/r
ack-1.2.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:46:in `initialize'
2011-05-04T13:09:18+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/r
ack-1.2.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:63:in `new'
2011-05-04T13:09:18+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/r
ack-1.2.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:63:in `map'
2011-05-04T13:09:18+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /home/heroku_rack/heroku.ru:18:in `
block (2 levels) in <main>'
2011-05-04T13:09:18+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/r
ack-1.2.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:46:in `instance_eval'
2011-05-04T13:09:18+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/r
ack-1.2.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:46:in `initialize'
2011-05-04T13:09:18+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /home/heroku_rack/heroku.ru:11:in `
new'
2011-05-04T13:09:18+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /home/heroku_rack/heroku.ru:11:in `
block in <main>'
2011-05-04T13:09:18+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/r
ack-1.2.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:46:in `instance_eval'
2011-05-04T13:09:18+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/r
ack-1.2.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:46:in `initialize'
2011-05-04T13:09:18+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /home/heroku_rack/heroku.ru:1:in `n
ew'
2011-05-04T13:09:18+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /home/heroku_rack/heroku.ru:1:in `<
main>'
2011-05-04T13:09:18+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /usr/ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/
gems/thin-1.2.6/lib/rack/adapter/loader.rb:36:in `eval'
2011-05-04T13:09:18+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /usr/ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/
gems/thin-1.2.6/lib/rack/adapter/loader.rb:36:in `load'
2011-05-04T13:09:18+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /usr/ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/
gems/thin-1.2.6/lib/thin/controllers/controller.rb:175:in `load_rackup_config'
2011-05-04T13:09:18+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /usr/ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/
gems/thin-1.2.6/lib/thin/controllers/controller.rb:65:in `start'
2011-05-04T13:09:18+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /usr/ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/
gems/thin-1.2.6/lib/thin/runner.rb:177:in `run_command'
2011-05-04T13:09:18+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /usr/ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/
gems/thin-1.2.6/lib/thin/runner.rb:143:in `run!'
2011-05-04T13:09:18+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /usr/ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/
gems/thin-1.2.6/bin/thin:6:in `<top (required)>'
2011-05-04T13:09:18+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /usr/ruby1.9.2/bin/thin:19:in `load
'
2011-05-04T13:09:18+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /usr/ruby1.9.2/bin/thin:19:in `<mai
n>'
2011-05-04T06:09:19-07:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2011-05-04T06:10:23-07:00 heroku[slugc]: Slug compilation started
2011-05-04T06:11:35-07:00 heroku[api]: Deploy d611756 by mail@domain.dk

2011-05-04T06:11:36-07:00 heroku[slugc]: Slug compilation finished
2011-05-04T06:11:36-07:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to created
2011-05-04T06:11:36-07:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from created to starting
2011-05-04T13:11:44+00:00 app[web.1]: !!!!! DEPRECATION NOTICE !!!!!
2011-05-04T13:11:44+00:00 app[web.1]: The WWW constant is deprecated, please swi
tch to the new top-level Mechanize
2011-05-04T13:11:44+00:00 app[web.1]: constant.  WWW will be removed in Mechaniz
e version 2.0
2011-05-04T13:11:44+00:00 app[web.1]:
2011-05-04T13:11:44+00:00 app[web.1]: You've referenced the WWW constant from /a
pp/lib/scraper.rb:4:in `<class:Scraper>', please
2011-05-04T13:11:44+00:00 app[web.1]: switch the "WWW" to "Mechanize".  Thanks!
2011-05-04T13:11:44+00:00 app[web.1]:
2011-05-04T13:11:44+00:00 app[web.1]: Sincerely,
2011-05-04T13:11:44+00:00 app[web.1]:
2011-05-04T13:11:44+00:00 app[web.1]:   Pew Pew Pew
2011-05-04T13:11:49+00:00 app[web.1]: >> Thin web server (v1.2.6 codename Crazy
Delicious)
2011-05-04T13:11:49+00:00 app[web.1]: >> Maximum connections set to 1024
2011-05-04T13:11:49+00:00 app[web.1]: >> Listening on 0.0.0.0:10216, CTRL+C to s
top
2011-05-04T06:11:49-07:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2011-05-04T13:11:49+00:00 app[web.1]:
2011-05-04T13:11:49+00:00 app[web.1]:
2011-05-04T13:11:49+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/" for IP at 2011-05
-04 15:11:49 +0200
2011-05-04T13:11:49+00:00 app[web.1]:
2011-05-04T13:11:49+00:00 app[web.1]: ActionView::MissingTemplate (Missing layou
t layouts/Application with {:handlers=>[:erb, :rjs, :builder, :rhtml, :rxml], :f
ormats=>[:html], :locale=>[:en, :en]} in view paths "/app/app/views", "/app/vend
or/plugins/tinymce_hammer/app/views", "/app/vendor/plugins/rails_log_stdout/app/
views", "/app/vendor/plugins/rails3_disable_x_sendfile/app/views", "/app/.bundle
/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/devise-1.3.4/app/views", "/app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gem
s/kaminari-0.12.4/app/views"):
2011-05-04T13:11:49+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/controllers/public_controller.rb:13:
in `index'
2011-05-04T13:11:49+00:00 app[web.1]:
2011-05-04T13:11:49+00:00 app[web.1]:
2011-05-04T13:11:49+00:00 heroku[router]: GET www.mydomain.dk/ dyno=web.1 qu
eue=0 wait=3229ms service=307ms bytes=934
2011-05-04T06:11:50-07:00 heroku[nginx]: GET / HTTP/1.1 | IP | 964 | ht
tp | 500
2011-05-04T06:15:51-07:00 heroku[slugc]: Slug compilation started
2011-05-04T06:17:00-07:00 heroku[api]: Deploy 5065c05 by mail@domain.dk

2011-05-04T06:17:00-07:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to bouncing
2011-05-04T06:17:00-07:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from created to starting
2011-05-04T06:17:01-07:00 heroku[slugc]: Slug compilation finished
2011-05-04T13:17:02+00:00 app[web.1]: >> Stopping ...
2011-05-04T13:17:13+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesu
pport-3.0.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:304:in `rescue in depend_on': No
such file to load -- scraper (LoadError)
2011-05-04T13:17:13+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/a
ctivesupport-3.0.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:299:in `depend_on'
2011-05-04T13:17:13+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/a
ctivesupport-3.0.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:216:in `require_dependency
'
2011-05-04T13:17:13+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/r
ailties-3.0.3/lib/rails/engine.rb:138:in `block (2 levels) in eager_load!'
2011-05-04T13:17:13+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/r
ailties-3.0.3/lib/rails/engine.rb:137:in `each'
2011-05-04T13:17:13+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/r
ailties-3.0.3/lib/rails/engine.rb:137:in `block in eager_load!'
2011-05-04T13:17:13+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/r
ailties-3.0.3/lib/rails/engine.rb:135:in `each'
2011-05-04T13:17:13+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/r
ailties-3.0.3/lib/rails/engine.rb:135:in `eager_load!'
2011-05-04T13:17:13+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/r
ailties-3.0.3/lib/rails/application/railties.rb:11:in `each'
2011-05-04T13:17:13+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/r
ailties-3.0.3/lib/rails/application/railties.rb:11:in `all'
2011-05-04T13:17:13+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/r
ailties-3.0.3/lib/rails/application.rb:107:in `eager_load!'
2011-05-04T13:17:13+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/r
ailties-3.0.3/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:41:in `block in <module:Finisher
>'
2011-05-04T13:17:13+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/r
ailties-3.0.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:25:in `instance_exec'
2011-05-04T13:17:13+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/r
ailties-3.0.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:25:in `run'
2011-05-04T13:17:13+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/r
ailties-3.0.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:50:in `block in run_initializers'
2011-05-04T13:17:13+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/r
ailties-3.0.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:49:in `each'
2011-05-04T13:17:13+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/r
ailties-3.0.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:49:in `run_initializers'
2011-05-04T13:17:13+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/r
ailties-3.0.3/lib/rails/application.rb:134:in `initialize!'
2011-05-04T13:17:13+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/r
ailties-3.0.3/lib/rails/application.rb:77:in `method_missing'
2011-05-04T13:17:13+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/config/environment.rb:4:in `<t
op (required)>'
2011-05-04T13:17:13+00:00 app[web.1]:   from <internal:lib/rubygems/custom_requi
re>:29:in `require'
2011-05-04T13:17:13+00:00 app[web.1]:   from <internal:lib/rubygems/custom_requi
re>:29:in `require'
2011-05-04T13:17:13+00:00 app[web.1]:   from config.ru:3:in `block (3 levels) in
 <main>'
2011-05-04T13:17:13+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /home/heroku_rack/heroku.ru:23:in `
eval'
2011-05-04T13:17:13+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /home/heroku_rack/heroku.ru:23:in `
block (3 levels) in <main>'
2011-05-04T13:17:13+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/r
ack-1.2.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:46:in `instance_eval'
2011-05-04T13:17:13+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/r
ack-1.2.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:46:in `initialize'
2011-05-04T13:17:13+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/r
ack-1.2.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:63:in `new'
2011-05-04T13:17:13+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/r
ack-1.2.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:63:in `map'
2011-05-04T13:17:13+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /home/heroku_rack/heroku.ru:18:in `
block (2 levels) in <main>'
2011-05-04T13:17:13+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/r
ack-1.2.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:46:in `instance_eval'
2011-05-04T13:17:13+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/r
ack-1.2.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:46:in `initialize'
2011-05-04T13:17:13+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /home/heroku_rack/heroku.ru:11:in `
new'
2011-05-04T13:17:13+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /home/heroku_rack/heroku.ru:11:in `
block in <main>'
2011-05-04T13:17:13+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/r
ack-1.2.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:46:in `instance_eval'
2011-05-04T13:17:13+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /usr/ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/
gems/thin-1.2.6/lib/rack/adapter/loader.rb:36:in `eval'
2011-05-04T13:17:13+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /usr/ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/
gems/thin-1.2.6/bin/thin:6:in `<top (required)>'
2011-05-04T06:17:14-07:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2011-05-04T13:17:26+00:00 heroku[router]: Error H10 (App crashed) -> GET www.vin
derhimlen.dk/ dyno=none queue=0 wait=0ms service=0ms bytes=0

PC /c/rails/myapp (master)
$ '
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the log there is...

```
No such file to load -- scraper
```

Is the scraper gem in your Gemfile?

Comment: Your answer help my to find a solution to the crashing

Answer (score 0):

```
2011-05-04T18:18:13+00:00 app[web.1]: ActionView::MissingTemplate (Missing layou
t layouts/Application with {:handlers=>[:erb, :rjs, :builder, :rhtml, :rxml], ...
```

Looks like you might be missing the main layout file, normally located in `app/views/layouts/application.html.erb`.

Answer (score 0):

```
ActionView::MissingTemplate (Missing layou
t layouts/Application with {:handlers=>[:erb, :rjs, :builder, :rhtml, :rxml], :f
ormats=>[:html], :locale=>[:en, :en]} in view paths "/app/app/views", "/app/vend
or/plugins/tinymce_hammer/app/views", "/app/vendor/plugins/rails_log_stdout/app/
views", "/app/vendor/plugins/rails3_disable_x_sendfile/app/views", "/app/.bundle
/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/devise-1.3.4/app/views", "/app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gem
s/kaminari-0.12.4/app/views"):
```

Have you

```
$ git add 'app/views/layouts/Application.html.erb'
$ git commit -m 'why isnt this file already in there?'
$ git push heroku master
```

?

I've had files that I *really* thought were in the repo not actually be there. Always a surprise when they crop up.